# PostgreSQL - GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function confluence

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run some query which will bring an output of contact created per user, i get the below error when running the query, any ideas?

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "user_mapping.lower_username" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    lower_username AS "Username", 
    display_name AS "Full Name", 
    count(DISTINCT CONTENT.title) AS "Pages created"
FROM 
    CONTENT
    LEFT JOIN 
    USER_MAPPING ON CONTENT.creator = USER_MAPPING.user_key
    LEFT JOIN 
    CWD_USER ON USER_MAPPING.lower_username = CWD_USER.lower_user_name
WHERE 
    creator IS NOT NULL AND 
    CONTENTTYPE IN ('PAGE', 'BLOGPOST')
GROUP BY creator
ORDER BY "Pages created" DESC;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause+or+be+used+in+an+aggregate+function

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have case like this:

```
lower_username   creator
-------------------------
A                X
B                X
C                Y
D                Y
```

if you try to group by creator, system doesn't know how to handle lower_username. It will be either

```
lower_username   creator
-------------------------
A                X
C                Y
```

OR

```
lower_username   creator
-------------------------
B                X
D                Y
```

Because of that you need to group by rest of the columns as well (lower_username in my example), or to apply some aggregate function on non-grouped columns (for example, AVG, MAX etc...). You need to have for one grouped value only one value in other columns too (if you selected them by select statement).

Comment: Great thing mate, thank you for your great explanation, it works now.

Comment: I tried to vote but it seems like I need 15 points in order to vote :\